# What is the mix of Chimera in Spy x Family?

Tags: spy-x-family

In Spy family, Anya has a doll chimera.

What mix of animal is the chimera to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is clearly mentioned in the story, but [this](https://yakuneba-ten.jp/spyfamily-kimerasan/) for example says 'with lion's head and snake's tail'.